# (Need Explanation) Don't get what fragment code means

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to understand this part of the code from 11.3 of [THIS SITE](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html#fragments_tutorial_listfragment):

```
if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
  fragment.setText(link);
} else {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
      DetailActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_URL, link);
  startActivity(intent);

}
```

The site says that `Detail Activity` is called when no other fragments are present in the layout. What does that mean? Won't there always be a fragment in the layout?

I think I'm more confused at which file gets run first because I'm not sure how the application would know which layout to use in case of portrait or landscape orientation. Is there a part in the code which tells the app to use a specific set of instructions for each orientation?

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its done by folder.  If there's a file by the same name in the layout-land or layout-port folder, it will switch between the two on rotation by destroying the old Activity and creating a new one.  Actually the recreation will always happen, but it will automatically detect which version to use if there are multiple layout xmls of the same name.

Comment: OK I think I'm slowly starting to understand this. So you're saying that when the app is run, the app looks for the xml filefrom layout, or layout-port folder depending on the orientation. 

Just a follow up to that, which xml file would it run first from the layout folders (after determining which one to use)? Right now I have `activity_detail.xml` and `activity_rssfeed.xml` in my layout/ports folder.

Comment: Whichever one you tell it to in setContentView.

Comment: OOOOHHHHHHH THANKS! It all finally clicked in!